# Overhead in jQuery.Deferred().done/fail/always/then?

Tags: jquery, callback, deferred

I have a lot of places where I want to ensue that a given `promise` has been resolved, such as:

```
promise = getData();
promise.done(function(data) {
    ...do something to data ...
});
```

I may wind up with thousands of `done` calls like the above where the promise has been resolved even upon calling `getData()`. What is the overhead if I use deferred callbacks like this?

As far as I could see, `Deferred()` is based on `jQuery.Callbacks()` with memory, and it seems as if adding a handler on a resolved or rejected promise won't add the callback to any queues anywhere and just call (or dump) it right away (depending on the end state). But is it best practise to do like this?